# Execute Shell Script in Post build and store Output

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins

I have added  Shell Script (in post build Task) which executes CURL statements.

The Curl statements gives some output which I want to refer later in my Shell Script, currently I am unable to achieve this.
Is there some way wherein it can be achieved.

I have searched for plugins but dint find any satisfactory answer to the requirement.

Comment: Is this output in plain text?

Comment: It will be alphanumeric characteristics which I would be capturing in ".txt" file and later want to grep from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text as follows:

```
def proc = "<your culr command>".execute()
echo proc.in.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell syntax to capture this output:

```
curl_output=$(curl http://your.curl.query)
echo $curl_output
```

You will capture everything in your variable. Then you can use it whenever you want.

This is also working if you are calling a shell script:

```
output=$(./yourscript.sh)
echo $output
```

Your variable will catch everything that you `echo` during your execution